# ColumnSeries takes a lot of time to render using Syncfusion for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, charts, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

Using the latest version of SfChart for Xamarin.Forms (16.3.0.36) I am encountering the following issue: ColumnSeries takes a lot of time to render a small collection (more than 10 seconds for a collection of a few records) compared to LineSeries (less than 3 seconds for the same collection size).

In fact, using the debugger I discovered that loading the view containing the ColumnSeries Chart is the most time-consuming part, even before the data for the graph is set. I use the LineSeries in the same way and it loads much faster.

I am using the following code for the ColumnSeries:

```
            <chart:SfChart x:Name="SumChart1" Margin="5,0,10,0">
            <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                <chart:DateTimeAxis Title="Time" EdgeLabelsDrawingMode="Center"
                                    IntervalType="{Binding IntervalType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    x:Name="SumAxis" />
            </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

            <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
                <chart:NumericalAxis Title="{Binding SelectedVariableForGraph.Name}" />
            </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

            <chart:ColumnSeries
                x:Name="SumSeries"
                Label="Sum"
                XBindingPath="Key"
                YBindingPath="Value"
                ItemsSource="{Binding SumGraph, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ListenPropertyChange="True"
            >
                <chart:ColumnSeries.ColorModel>
                    <chart:ChartColorModel>
                        <chart:ChartColorModel.CustomBrushes>
                            <Color>Orange</Color>
                        </chart:ChartColorModel.CustomBrushes>
                    </chart:ChartColorModel>
                </chart:ColumnSeries.ColorModel>
            </chart:ColumnSeries>
        </chart:SfChart>
```

I am only interested in fixing the Android version.
I have tested the issue using both HAXM Android Emulator and Xiaomi Mi A1 device, with similar results (the device seems only a bit faster).

While searching for an answer to this issue, I found that "SfChart renders column series in Android and iOS as FastColumn series by default" (https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/138607/fastcolumnbitmapseries-on-sfchart-xforms), but this does not seem to work in my case (for Android).

Is there something that I am missing?

EDIT:
I am using a SfTabItem to show a chart (I have 3 ColumnSeries and 1 Series charts in the page). The X axis is of type DateTime and the Y axis is of type double. This detail seems to be causing the issue

Comment: Hi, can you let me know, how many data that small collection holds, so that we can prepare a sample based on that and provide you. Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: @MICHAELPRABHU 10 elements would be enough. Not the amount of data seems to be the issue but the actual rendering. Please note that I am showing the charts inside SfTabItems - 4 tabs, each one with a chart inside (I don't know if wrapper elements can interefere in the process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the reported scenario at our end and i like to let you know that in your sample you have given only interval type as days for all the charts, but the bound values are in difference like months and years, so that it takes too much of time to render. Because auto interval is calculated, and gridline is rendered for all the days from so many years. So, you must set **Interval** and **IntervalType** based on the given data or you do need to set anything and chart will automatically calculates the interval and interval type based on the data . We have modified your sample based on that and it can be downloaded from the below link.

[sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/TABVIE~1-1466779618.zip)

Answer (score 0):

We were not able to reproduce the reported issue at our end and we have prepared a sample and can be download the sample from the below link.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/222458/ze/222458443814772.zip)

Since we are not aware of your exact application scenario, we were not able to reproduce this issue at our end, so can you please revert us by modifying the sample based on your application along with replication procedure. This will be helpful for us to investigate further and provide you a better solution at the earliest.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with a sample. I have managed to modify the sample so that the scenario can be reproduced. I have uploaded the code here https://uploadfiles.io/fsp74 . Using the HAXM emulator it now takes about 7 seconds for the screen with the tabs to load, and about 3 seconds to change the tabs. The main change to the sample is changing the type of X axis from double to DateTime.

Comment: Hello geetha rajendran, @MICHAELPRABHU . Can you please let me know if you were able to reproduce the issue using the code I provided in the previous comment? I need to know if I should continue to use SfChart in the current project or look for another approach.